# Setup table column width

Tags: php, html-table

I am trying to setup a table column width to only 200px or 10%. However, when I populate the data from the database, the column seems to ignore the column width and expand it as much as it can. Here is my table html.

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><a href='#'>City</a></th>   
        <th width='200' class='table_width'><a href='#'>name</a></th> 
        <th><a href='#'>Agent</a></th>
        <th>... 
    //I have tried class and width attribute. both don't work. 
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        <tr>
            //these column data were popluated from database
            <td><?= $row->city; ?></td>
            <td width='200' class='table_width'><?= $row->_name; ?></td>  
            //ignore the width and expand the table cell. 
            <td><?= $row->agent; ?></td> 
            <td>...

        </tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `word-wrap:break-word;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/RF4F6/1/

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th> 
            <th>Col 3</th> 
            <th>Col 4</th> 
            <th>Col 5</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Normal Width</td>
            <td>Normal Width</td>
            <td class="forcedWidth">hiThisIsAreallyLongStringThatWillHaveToWrapAt200PixelsOrI'llBeUnhappyAndYouWon'tLikeMeWhenI'mUnhappy.</td>
            <td>Normal Width</td>
            <td>NormalWidth</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table td{
     padding:.5em; /* Not essential for this answer, just a little buffer for the jsfiddle */
}

.forcedWidth{
    width:200px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Metal. I tried but still not working. The table cell width still expend all the way even in your demo. +1 though.

Answer (score 2):

This is the standard behaviour of a table cell.

One way to do this is place a div inside your cells with `style="width: 200px; overflow-hidden;"`

Comment: I tried but have no luck. I thought overflow is for height not width. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 1):

Using `table-layout: fixed` for table will force browser to maintain specified dimensions.

Comment: Ah, for `table-layout: fixed` to work, you should also specify some exact width for table itself. See http://jsfiddle.net/vVN2P/

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. It seems like that your code only restrain cell width but not the contents.

Comment: Exactly. Your question is telling us about column width, and nothing about wrapping text lines.